# Bhagavata Maha Purana and Gayatri Mantra

Tags: bhagavata-purana, gayatri-mantra, matsya-purana

Matsya Maha Purana chapter 53, slokha 20 says the following:

> यत्राधिक्र्त्य गायत्रीम् वर्ण्यते धर्मविस्तर: | व्र्त्रासुरवधोपेतम् तत्भागवतमुछ्यते ||

> Translation: The Purana that contains The Gayatri mantra at the beginning, and elaborates various forms of Dharmas, and contains the account of the slaying of VrtrAsura, is known as (Srimad) Bhagavatam.

Now my question is, does Srimad Bhagavata Mahapurana (NOT the Devi Bhagavatam) contain The Gayatri Mantra at the beginning (or the beginning chapters)? The print version I have does not seem to begin with the Gayatri Mantra, but I may have overlooked something. Hence this question.

Thanks in advance for answers and notes.

Note: Kindly don't take this as a dispute of authenticity, or a debate involving Srimad Bhagavatam vs Sri Devi Bhagavatam. I am aware of that debate, and the goal here is not to have another one here.

Comment: Gayatri refers to a mantra in a written/chanted in particular metre, not to one specific.mantra.

Comment: The Gayatri Upasana is given in the greatest of details in the Devi Bhagavatam and not the Bhagavata Purana. BTW, what is the source of your translation of the quoted verse?

Comment: @Rickross the translation is mine as I have some background in Sanskrit. It is a quick translation but it is mostly correct (I can do a word by word if that helps, but didn't think it was necessary). Secondly it does not specifically talk about Gayatri upasana as a deity upasana, it simply says GayatrIm which can also be taken as The Gayatri mantra. Even if you take it as a deity as opposed to Mantra, the question still remains. Is such a verse in Srimad Bhagavatam (not in my copy). I know The Devi Bhagavatam has references to Gayatri, also has a Gayatri mantra in the second chapter or so.

Comment: Just for completeness - The Gayatri mantra that Sri Devi Bhagavatam contains in the first or second chapter (forgot and can't recall the exact chapter off the top of my head) is not the same one(s) in the Rg Veda. It is a different mantra (sarva chaitanya rupAm tAmAdhyam vidyAm cha DhImahI | buddhim yAna prachOdayAt ||). 
But as I stated in my question, my query is specific to Srimad Bhagavatam, and my question is to confirm my observation (that no such reference to Gayatri, either as a deity or mantra is in Srimad Bhagavata Maha Purana either in the first chapter or the first few chapters)

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thank you for your kind response. That's an interesting thought, but I dont find such a verse in Srimad Bhagavatam in the first chapter. Does Your Holiness find such a reference? If yes, kindly let me know.

Comment: @idolworshipper though it is interesting, personally I don't see how a reference to _"DHImahI"_ alone constitutes the basis for Gayatri mantra. _satyam param DHImahI"_ is a well known verse / phrase - Just that I do not see how that one word makes it a Gayatri mantra (I mean grammatically / structurally).

Comment: "the translation is mine " --- Okay @Vidyarthi

Comment: @Rickross you could also check online versions of Matsya Purana to see if they offer a different meaning or interpretation. I checked the one by Parimal Publications, and it gives the same meaning for the verse. The verse is really simple Sanskrit so I do not expect the meaning to be much different. Interpretations of course can vary

Comment: @idolworshipper I will check Sridhara's commentary. Thanks. I already have an account on JSTOR (for long time), so thanks for the pointer to the article.

Comment: @PrasannaR Thanks for your answer. While I respect your reservations in sharing things you consider to be secret, I have a healthy disagreement on deleting questions. It is up to an individual to share things based on one's own faith. As a knowledge seeking forum, if we start deleting questions this way, people from other faiths, other branches of Hinduism can mount arguments with similar reasoning, causing deletion of many questions in this forum. That could make this counter productive. I respect all schools, and an individual's choice to share things based on one's own faith. Thanks again.

Comment: @idolworshipper checked the paper you pointed to, and I see Sridhara Swami interprets _"DHImahI"_ to mean reference to Gayatri. This is one possible answer to my question, so if you want to write this up as an answer (as opposed to comment), I can accept it. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: The translation is a bit off. "अधिकृत्य" does not mean "beginning with" as you have assumed. It just means, "taking or using Gayatri as main basis or theme", which is applicable to any scripture with claims of authenticity and loftiness.

Comment: @RamAbloh Thanks for the answer. I have an agreement and disagreement. First let me state where I agree with you. I agree to the meaning you stated as well. I am aware that meaning also applies (as in the main theme), but I didn't think that meaning applied in this case, and here is the reason. That meaning would make this verse too generic to serve the purpose in the Matsya Purana. The verse occurs in Matsya Purana where it reveals the characteristics of Bhagavata Purana. That meaning could point to any text like you mentioned, where Matsya Purana lists the characteristics of various Puranas.

Comment: @RamAbloh That said I disagree with your take on my translation. _"अधिकृत्य"_ could simply mean being positioned at the top / beginning etc. I see that as one of the direct meanings, and not an assumption. But as for which meaning is right, that will depend on interpretations. Like I stated in one of my earlier messages, I also checked a print publication, and that gives a meaning similar to mine. I will try to check other sources, and I would very much request and welcome your research, so that we can compare notes. But अधिकृत्य does mean something like _"positioned at the beginning / top_

Comment: @RamAbloh But I totally agree your meaning is also correct, and may even be the right one for this verse in Matsya Purana. Just that I need more data / facts to convince myself which one is right. Any further pointers from you will be most welcome. For discussion let us assume Matsya Purana indeed meant something like "regarding" or "main theme" as you stated. Still that leaves my question open- how is the first verse of Srimad Bhagavatam really about Gayatri? One answer of course is what idolworshipper pointed to, which is the interpretation of Sridhara Swami. I look forward to more answers